# Purpose of [reporting] tag

Tags: discussion, clean-up, meta-tags

I draw your attention to the [reporting](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reporting) tag.

Currently 14 questions, and they run the gamut:

- using Google Spreadsheets to make a report
- scheduling reports in HP Project and Portfolio Management Center
- reporting a false/incorrect block on Facebook (× 2)
- generating a report from multiple Trello boards
- reporting phishing emails to Gmail
- dealing with a false spam report on Facebook
- reporting an "improper" Wikipedia article
- reporting a fake profile on Facebook
- reporting spam on Wikipedia
- an extraordinarily unclear question about PayPal and reports
- emailing reports from Google Analytics
- reporting a bug in Google+
- reporting abuse to a web hosting company

There is, of course, no tag usage guidance and no description.

I suggest that this tag is too broad and too ill-defined to be useful. It's also getting used for two very different purposes: "informing" someone/some system of a problem and generating "reports" to display data.

The reports from an app are going to be very specific to that app. There're no "report" gurus. There may be Google Spreadsheet report gurus, or Trello report gurus, but they'll just be gurus for the appropriate app.

As for "informing", I suggest that spam reporting is well-covered by [spam-prevention](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spam-prevention). As for other forms of abuse, I suppose a case could be made for an `abuse-report` tag, but even that seems too meta.

Can anyone make the case that this tag should stay? If it stays, what should it be used for (since it can't be used for both purposes)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All questions have been retagged and the tag has been removed by the system.